# How to get and manipulate existing data from firebase in angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have existing data in firebase which is array of objects [image]

I have a component which is meant to add new data to this existing data. How can I get this (existing) data? When I use HttpClient.get it returns me this [image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect, and explain what you're trying to do with that code.

Comment: `HttpClient.get` is returning an `Observable` so to launch the request you need to subscribe to it `this.http.get('url').subscribe(yourDataHere => console.log(yourDataHere);`